# What is the effect of H2O2 on SPIONs?

Tags: oxides, iron

I have a system contains super paramagnetic iron oxide nanoparticles (SPIONs) either Fe3+ or Fe2+. I need to introduce hydrogen peroxide to the system but i am not sure about its effect to the SPIONs if it can degrade SPIONs or make any change?

Comment: $\ce{H2O2}$ is at ambient conditions a liquid and a capable oxidizer.  Not only would it be likely that it transfers $\ce{Fe^{2+}}$ into $\ce{Fe^{3+}}$, the very same ions likely catalyze the decomposition of $\ce{H2O2}$.  This is why I'm going to vote to close the question.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is barely more than a comment. If you add hydrogen peroxide to nanoparticles of an iron oxide such as hematite or magnetite, the hydrogen peroxide will decompose to H<sub>2</sub>O and O<sub>2</sub>. Smut (Fe<sub>3</sub>O<sub>4</sub>) on stainless steel from etching with FeCl<sub>3</sub> is dislodged when treated with H<sub>2</sub>O<sub>2</sub>; oxygen bubbles up and knocks the iron oxide off.

However, SPIONs are not just nanoparticles of paramagnetic oxides, but are stabilized in the dispersion, coated by surfactants and treated with drugs for delivery to specific locations (Ref 1). The individual particles start out quite small:

[image]

and are engineered to be stable in the blood system, but whether and to what extent they are sufficiently protected to withstand chemical attack from hydrogen peroxide is a question to be determined by experiment.

I would suggest adding the H<sub>2</sub>O<sub>2</sub> to the SPION concoction and look for bubbling - but even if all the H<sub>2</sub>O<sub>2</sub> decomposes, it need not signify the total decomposition of all the SPION.

Ref 1. Advanced Drug Delivery Reviews 63 (2011) 24–46; M. Mahmoudi et al.